# Find associated records through third table association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 3 models I am working with and trying to find the most frequent items between two models that are not related, but have a third table that is.

My 3 models are:
Visits (has_many Diagnoses)
Diagnosis (belongs_to Visit)
Prescriptions (belongs_to Visit)

Given a specific diagnosis, I want to know what drug is most commonly prescribed. Since Diagnosis and Prescriptions don't have a direct relationship I am lost.  Below is my current code

This gets my top diagnoses

```
@top_diag = Diagnosiswork.group("diagnosis").order("count_diagnosis_id desc").limit(10).count("diagnosis_id")
```

This is in my view

```
      <tbody>
        <% @top_diag.each do |diagnosis, count| %>
            <% top_visits = Diagnosiswork.where(diagnosis_id: diagnosis.id) %>
            <% top_prescription = Prescription.where(visit_id: @top_visits) %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= count %>: <%= diagnosis.id %></td><td><strong><%= diagnosis.name %></strong></td>
        <td>
         <% top_prescription.each do |prescription| %>
            <%= prescription.medicine.full_name %>
         <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Active</span></td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

This gets me a list of drugs, but it is the same list for every diagnosis.  My current thought is to get the Visits where these diagnosis are used the most, and then use a query similar to my top_diag that uses a where clause singling out certain visits.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I suspect that, without an explicit relationship between `Diagnosis` and `Prescription`, you won't be able to determine which drug is most commonly prescribed for a given diagnosis. You could try to do some inference (e.g., drugs that are most prescribed for visits that include a particular diagnosis). But, things *could* get tricky - for instance, with high prevalence comorbidities.

Comment: You hit what I am looking to do.  Drugs that are most prescribed for visits that have a particular diagnosis.

Comment: What's the relationship between `Prescription` and `Medicine`? (e.g., `Prescription belongs_to :medicine` and `Medicine has_many :prescriptions`?)

Comment: A prescription belongs_to a medicine and a medicine has_many prescriptions.  In theory a person is given a prescription and that ties to one of the medicines in the database.

Comment: Could you make `Prescription` belong to a `Diagnosis` instead?  Then a visit could still have prescriptions through diagnoses and you'd have the relationship you'd need.